# Как удалённо получить список активных пользователей windows на c#?

Tags: c#, windows, сеть

Нужно получить список активных пользователей на каждом компьютере в ЛВС, как это можно сделать?

Comment: задачи автоматизации администрирования хорошо решаются с помощью WMI (System.Management), разобраться в нем немного сложно, но инструмент мощный, позволяет почти все при наличии соответствующих прав у пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь решена эта проблема.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212155/how-to-get-logged-on-users-with-their-status-on-remote-machine)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string ComputerName = "remote-machine";
            ManagementScope Scope;

            if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                Conn.Username = "username";
                Conn.Password = "password";
                Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
            }
            else
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

            Scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT LogonId  FROM Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType=2");
            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

            foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "LogonId", WmiObject["LogonId"]);// String
                ObjectQuery LQuery = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" + WmiObject["LogonId"] + "} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent");
                ManagementObjectSearcher LSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, LQuery);
                foreach (ManagementObject LWmiObject in LSearcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "Name", LWmiObject["Name"]);                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотри подробно на псевдоним WMI - NETLOGON

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx